# problem with laptop fan after ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04

After i install ubuntu os, my laptop become warm and it's fan work like's when you play high-graphics game on windows.

now actually im running ubuntu without any os like windows. its just linux. so whats cause my pc to work like that ?

why it like this on linux ?

Comment: Open the "System monitor" utility, look on the "Processes" tab, is there anything using a large CPU % ?

Comment: no, all of the proccess are using 0 percent of CPU Usagem but one of them is using system usage that i shot a pic (https://i.imgsafe.org/189a87a4c0.png) @JonasCz

Comment: Regarding your screenshot: its sorted by process name instead by CPU usage. Like that it might be misleading as it might show the wrong part of your processes.

Comment: I am guessing here that a missing graphic card driver might be the issue. Please open `Software & Updates` and check the tab `Additional drivers`. In case you dont feel comfortable choosing yourself add a screenshot of that and the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question

Comment: thanks. here is the shot of driver (https://i.imgsafe.org/1a4a5dc189.png) and output of that code (https://i.imgsafe.org/1a4ff21941.png) @dufte

Comment: Well you could try switching to one of those 2 NVIDIA binary drivers and see if that makes a difference. But i am somehow confused as the first screenshot tells that you have an NV card while lspci output looks like an intel one. Could it be you have a hybrid card like optimus or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I would also try the manufacturer's graphics driver if possible after installing the best thermal sensor modules suited to your hardware, the possible good choices found by running sudo sensors-detect; apt-get install linux-tools-common, or see if that's compatible w/, esp if your proc is intel; it will install thermald, which has a better fan-ctrl dflt set; sensors-detect will run an interactive script to load modules at boot-time that will manage cooling better. Be sure and search ways to reduce laptop heat prior to following these suggestions, as your hrdware might work better w/ other apps, like TLP or something. dpkg and apt-cache showpkg cpufrequtils & explore ways to configure your avg processor load if you wish.